# How to solve '[Errno 111] Connection Refused' in Django app on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

I have just added a new app to my Django application, and everything was working fine locally. When I push it Heroku however, I get the following error when trying to access views from the new app, or admin pages related to it. The rest of the site is working fine.

## Error (from the heroku application logs):

```
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305769+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305769+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305770+00:00 app[web.1]:     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305770+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305771+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305771+00:00 app[web.1]:     return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305771+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305772+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305772+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise err
2017-02-15T10:14:13.305773+00:00 app[web.1]: error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

## Settings

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ******

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

ADMINS = (
    (***, ***),
)

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'feed',
    'cv',
    'hon',
    'blog',
    'markdown_deux',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =        
dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../feed/static/'),
)
```

I couldn't find much documentation for this particular error, so any help would be much appreciated. What's going wrong? Let me know if there's any more information I can provide that would help.

**Update:** Regarding the first two comments, my 'application' is a static website apart from the django admin backend, and I'm not trying to send emails anywhere in my code. The page that generates the error logs above is just the homepage of a simple blog, listing all the posts (of which there currently are none, because I'm unable to add any).

Comment: This is coming from smtplib, so presumably it's a problem when you're trying to send emails. You need to show the code that is calling this, as well as your settings.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, your traceback shows issue with smtplib, post your settings or email send code

Comment: Thank you both for your help, I've updated the question with the requested info. I'm not trying to send emails anywhere in my code, could heroku/django be doing that for some reason? I don't believe I'm using smtplib anywhere.

Comment: Do any of the modules try to save to the filesystem?

Comment: @NathanLoyer No, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Aand now it's resolved itself. Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the cause was, but this issue resolved itself after I made a dummy-change to one of the files (adding a space at the end of a line), and re-pushed the application to Heroku.

Comment: If anyone encounters the same problem and has a more enlightening solution, I'm happy to demote this from best answer.